# How to achieve CURL equivalent python code

Tags: python, curl

What is CURL equivalent approach in python?
For example in PHP:

```
$url = "http://example.com/";
$params = "?param1=" + $param1;
$params += "&param2=" + $param2;
$url = $url + $params;

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $httpReferer);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: use python requests to do it and for your params use a dict http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ca use pycurl. Here is an example of basic pycurl:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys
import pycurl

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.contents = ''

    def body_callback(self, buf):
        self.contents = self.contents + buf

sys.stderr.write("Testing %s\n" % pycurl.version)

t = Test()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://curl.haxx.se/dev/')
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, t.body_callback)
c.perform()
c.close()

print(t.contents)
```